# Is there work background services for Bluetooth low energy (BLE) on iOS?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I would like do coding in ios with Bluetooth low energy(BLE). i wanting to show notification of new BLE device while app background. is possible do it? I bought BLE Device from sensor tag site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible both in central and peripheral mode. You should declare the necessary permissions in your Info.plist and then you can search for one specific service in the background with the standard method `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:` of `CBCentralManager` Start with reading the [docs of Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html).

Comment: But I dnt know to find BLE Device UDID. i using '[centermanager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil option:nil]' method thn will get devices list in only foreground. if app background would not call to '-(void)centeralManager: didDiscoverPeripheral: advertisementData: RSSI:' method.

Comment: is working BLE device connection while background app without UDID?

Comment: I'm afraid not, the docs say "Apps that have specified the bluetooth-central background mode are allowed to scan while in the background. That said, they must explicitly scan for one or more services by specifying them in the serviceUUIDs parameter."

Comment: How can get serviceUUID?

Comment: **serviceUUID** is getting from advertisementData right?

Comment: yes, it is the same serviceUUID that can be found in advertisementData